# Как хранить график работы оборудования в бд?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть *самописная* система учета заявок по ремонту оборудования, в качестве бд используется Microsoft Sql Server редакция Express.

[image: Упрощенная схема бд]

Возникла необходимость учитывать простой оборудования в *рабочее время*.

Помогите модифицировать ( читать как какие таблицы необходимо добавить) приведенную схему так, что бы можно было получать время простоя оборудования в *рабочее время*. График работы может меняться (для каждой единицы оборудования). Историю изменения режимов работы необходимо сохранить, что бы при изменении режима бы возможность получить корректные данные. Заранее спасибо

---

Под простоем оборудования в рабочее время подразумевается следующее:

Предположим у нас есть закрытая заявка зарегистрированная в 10:00 закрытая в 23:15 этого же дня, режим работы данной единицы оборудования предположим с 07:00 до 17:00 тогда простой будет равен 7 часам, другой пример:
тот же режим работы, заявка зарегистрирована в 16:00 закрыта в 10:15 следующего дня простой в этом случае будет 4 часа 15 минут (1 час предыдущего дня и 3:15 текущего)

Comment: что значит "простой оборудования"? есть только одна запись, дата ее создания 10 часов, но рабочее время началось с 8 часов - как определить простой?

Comment: @BOPOH обновил вопрос

Comment: @Bald А почему 7 часов ? мне кажется что простой в вашем примере только с 7 до 10, т.е. 3 часа

Comment: @Mike c 7 до 10 оборудование работало, потом сломалось

Comment: т.е. "простой" - это время от `max(время_создания_заявки; начало_рабочего_дня)` до `min(время_закрытия_заявки; конец_рабочего_дня)`? А как мне тогда узнать рабочее время? Оно же меняться может, как оно хранится?

Comment: @BOPOH на текущий момент у меня этого нет, всмысле графика работ, так что рассматриваются любые варианты

Comment: @BOPOH обновил вопрос

Comment: если Requests - это заявка, RequestsHistory - история заявок -- почему две таблицы? т.к. "график работы может меняться", то надо создать таблицу [режим работы] (id, equipmentid, start, end). время простоя будете вычислять на основе выборки из Requests и [режим работы].

Comment: @Stack в принципе я тоже склонялся к этому варианту, только еще надо тогда период действия этого режима. думал может есть другие варианты

Comment: @Bald Офтоп: Какой софт позволяет рисовать такие красивые схемы?

Comment: _"только еще надо тогда период действия этого режима."_ -- лишнее. просто создаете новую запись. она отменяет прежнюю, т.к. при выборке берете запись с max  id

Comment: @RoulanD [dbForge Studio](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/sql/studio/)

Comment: @Stack да об этом я как то не подумал, спасибо

Comment: _"да об этом я как то не подумал, спасибо"_ -- пожалуйста. но я боюсь писать ответ :)

Comment: @Stack пока Вы *боялись* i-one уже написал :) если Вы напишите лучше я только за

Comment: @Bald У вас круглогодичный график у оборудования, т.е. без выходных и праздников. Если это не так, то вам же еще понадобится хранить некий календарь для обозначения нерабочих дней ...

Comment: @Mike очень хорошее замечание (про праздники). может Вы бы действительно написали ответ. а по поводу таблицы тут такое дело, что для некоторых единиц оборудования праздничный день может быть рабочим, а для некоторых выходным

Comment: @Bald Да, у меня появились некоторые идеи про праздники. Сегодня постараюсь сделать ответ ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таблицу `RequestHistories` или `Requests`, добавляете дату_время начала(Created) и окончания (Closed) ремонта в виде колонок типа datetime. Далее в тексте называю это таблицу просто `Requests`. И создаем следующие таблицы:

Основная таблица расписания работы оборудования:

```
create table EquipmentMode (
  Id int identity not null,
  EquipmentId int not null,         -- ID оборудования
  startTime time(0) not null,       -- Время начала рабочего дня
  endTime time(0) not null,         -- Время окончания рабочего дня
  weekday int not null default(62), -- Дни недели: битовая маска бит1(2)-Пн, бит7(128)-Вс, Пн-Пт=62
  workFrom date not null,           -- Дата начала действия записи расписания
  workTo date not null default('3000-01-01') -- Дата окончания действия
  )
```

В этой таблице для каждой единицы оборудования *должна* быть как минимум одна запись с расписанием. Рекомендую добавлять ее автоматически, в триггере при создании оборудования. Для упрощения запросов к этой таблице период действия записи делаем двумя полями - датой начала и окончания действия. Для активной в данный момент записи датой окончания ставим 1 янв 3000 года. (Можно null, но с ним потом работать менее удобно). Записи в таблице для конкретной единицы оборудования должны идти без разрывов в днях и без пересечений. Желательно делать контроль триггерами. Например, если есть запись для оборудования ID 1 заканчивающаяся 10 февраля 2016, после нее должна быть запись с 11 февраля 2016 по 3000 год.

Поле `weekday` число с установленными битами соответствующими рабочим дням недели оборудования. При Российских настройках MSSQL дни (номера бит) начинаются с понедельника. 0й бит не используется. Рабочая неделя Пон-Пят - установлены биты с 1 по 5 итого значение 62. Без выходных - 254. При Американских настройках MSSQL неделя будет начинаться в воскресенья, поэтому убедитесь, какой именно день недели первый на вашем сервере.

Исключения из стандартного расписания для праздников и других особых случаев:

```
create table holidays (
  Id int identity not null,
  EquipmentId int,                    -- NULL - для всех, ID - исключение для данного оборудования
  hDay date not null,                 -- Конкретный день, конкретного года
  isWork tinyint not null default(0)  -- 0 - праздник, 1 - рабочий день
)
```

В эту таблицу заранее на каждый год надо положить записи с праздничными днями. Для таких, общих, записей `EquipmentId=NULL`. Если согласно производственного календаря на данный год какой либо выходной объявляется перенесенным рабочим (суббота 20 февраля 2016, например) - то для него кладется запись с `isWork=1` - таким образом он становится исключением из стандартной проверки дней недели.

Если для какой то конкретной единицы оборудования существует нестандартное расписание праздников или конкретные выходные дни, в которое оно должно работать - в эту таблицу кладем запись с заполненным `EquipmentId` и `isWork` рабочий(1)/нерабочий(0).

Возможно имеет смысл заводить промежуточную таблицу с группами оборудования, для удобства задачи расписания сразу группе. Так же, возможно, стоит сделать в `EquipmentMode` записи с общим расписанием (eqId=NULL), что бы не создавать для каждой единицы отдельно. Решайте сами, как удобнее на вашем предприятии будет.

И еще нам понадобится служебная таблица с порядковыми номерами, для размножения записей в запросе. Количество записей в ней должно превышать максимально возможную продолжительность ремонта в днях:

```
create table seqnum(
 N int not null,
 CONSTRAINT PK_seqnum PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N)
);
insert into seqnum values(1),(2),(3),(4);
insert into seqnum select N+4 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select N+8 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select N+16 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select N+32 from seqnum; -- получили 64 записи.
```

Предполагаемая логика работы расписания: Если для данной единицы оборудования есть собственная запись в таблице `holidays` - то брать или не брать данный день в расчет берется только из нее. *Иначе* если в `holidays` есть общая запись на данный день - берем ее. *Иначе* сверяем день недели с битовой маской в `EquipmentMode`.

Запрос выбирающий простой по каждому дню по каждой единице оборудования выглядит примерно так:

```
select R.EquipmentId,R.id,R.cDay,R.sTime,R.eTime,E.weekDay & R.weekMask mask,
       E.startTime,E.endTime,gH.isWork,iH.isWork,
       case when E.startTime>R.sTime then E.startTime else R.sTime end t1,
       case when E.endTime<R.eTime then E.endTime else R.eTime end t2,
       -- Время простоя в минутах:
       (datediff(second,case when E.startTime>R.sTime then E.startTime else R.sTime end,
        case when E.endTime<R.eTime then E.endTime else R.eTime end)+59)/60 as mins

from ( -- подзапрос размножает заявки на все дни, пока они были открыты
   select R.id,R.EquipmentId,
          Cast(Created+N-1 as date) as cDay,      -- Конкретная дата
     case N when 1 then Cast(Created as time(0))
     else Cast('00:00' as time(0)) end as sTime,  -- Время начала
     case when Cast(Closed as Date)=Cast(Created+N-1 as date)
          then Cast(Closed as time(0))
          else Cast('23:59:59' as time(0)) end as eTime, -- Время окончания
          power(2,datepart(dw,Created+N-1)) as weekMask  -- Маска дня недели
     from requests R, seqnum S
    where S.N<=datediff(day, Created, Closed)+1
) as R
JOIN EquipmentMode as E on E.EquipmentId=R.EquipmentId and R.cDay between E.workFrom and E.workTo
LEFT JOIN holidays as gH on gH.hDay=R.cDay and gH.EquipmentId is null
LEFT JOIN holidays as iH on iH.hDay=R.cDay and iH.EquipmentId=R.EquipmentId
where coalesce(iH.isWork,gH.isWork,E.weekDay & R.weekMask)>0 -- проверка рабочий/выходной
  and R.eTime>E.startTime and R.sTime<E.endTime  -- Заявка в данный день окончилась до начала рабочего времени или открыта после
```

Выборку этого запроса группируете как вам необходимо и суммируете. Лишние поля из основной части запроса лучше убрать, я их ставил для удобства отладки и просмотра результата по дням. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79b2a/1/0)

Comment: огромное спасибо за столь развернутый ответ

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, я бы добавил одну таблицу (упрощённо) вида

```
create table EquipmentWorkingHours
(
    EquipmentId int,
    StartAt time,
    StopAt time,
    EffectiveSince datetime
)
```

Столбцы - это ID оборудования, режим работы, и дата, начиная с которой действует этот режим (до следующей большей даты для данного `EquipmentId`, если она есть, или до текущей и далее, если таковой нет).

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить следующую таблицу

```
/* режимы работы и история смены режимов работы */
create table EquipmentMode (
  Id int identity not null,
  EquipmentId int not null, 
  Start time not null,   -- начало работы оборудования
  End time not null,      
  Created datetime not null     -- дата смены режима работы
  )
```

Период действия режима работы хранить не надо, т.к. новая запись отменяет прежние, и при выборке актуального режима надо брать запись с max Id или max Created.
Время простоя надо вычислять на основе выборки из RequestHistories и EquipmentMode.
Cм. функцию [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189794(v=sql.120).aspx).
RequestHistories и Requests можно объединить.

Comment: спасибо за опубликованный ответ, указанная мной схема сильно *обрезана*. в реальной таблице есть дополнительные поля: например кто подал заявку, первоначальная причина ну и т.п. поэтому `Request` и `RequestHistories` это разные таблицы

Comment: _надо брать запись с max Id или max Created_  Да ладно, а если я хочу получить суммарный простой за месяц и в этом месяце трижды менялся график работы ... запрос для подклейки графика без интервала дат действия будет весьма нетривиальным

Comment: @Mike _"Да ладно"_ -- max id нужен для записи в RequestHistories. _"а если я хочу получить суммарный простой"_ -- берете join строк, делаете datediff'ы и т.д.

Comment: @Stack Беру datediff ... А дальше ? мне же надо найти минимальный diff, скажем больший нуля (если из даты записи вычитаем Created). И по индексу это никогда не пойдет. А between Created and Closed заметно шустрее и спокойно идет по индексам

Comment: @Mike _"Беру datediff ... А дальше ? ... А between Created and Closed заметно шустрее и спокойно идет по индексам"_ -- ок. сорри. я сейчас занят. комменты читают не все. интересные моменты могут затеряться. поэтому напишите свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В RequestHistories нужно добавить поле Closed datetime, IdleHours int, для подсчета использовать или хранимую процедуру или на языке программирования системы добавить логику подсчета. Нужно учитывать выходные, праздники, рабочие дни. Решать на голом SQL будет проблемно.

В простом случае достаточно добавить одно поле - время закрытия запроса, чтобы высчитывать из времени открытия и закрытия время простоя. Чтобы эту процедуру не повторять каждый раз - добавить поле "часы простоя", чтобы в дальнейшем уже брать из него.

Процедура - в момент редактирования поля "время закрытия" производится пересчет часов простоя и запись в соответствующее поле. Все отчеты берут информацию уже из этого поля.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: время закрытия заявки получается путем получения из `RequestHistories` последней записи. а для получения *времени простоя* необходимо еще знать и режим работы что бы из времени простоя убрать время когда станок не работает по графику